# Got a good answer before realizing question is a duplicate

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616415/size-of-pickled-numpy-arrays4). Then, after doing some research, found that [it was actually a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113549/sys-getsizeof-vaue-of-numpy-ndarray-seems-too-small). I've handled the duplication, flagging my question as a duplicate myself.

However, in the meantime, I got a pretty good answer to my question, which I think is better than the answers on the original question.

Will the new answer to my duplicate be lost? That would be a real pity to lose a good answer. What can be done about this?

Comment: Why is the answer lost? Was it deleted?

Comment: If the dupes are very closely related, you could flag and ask for a mod to merge the answer into the other question...

Comment: Your dupe target has 800+ views, the dupe target of your dupe target had 30+ views. I believe that the answer is not lost even if the last dupe is perhaps in the wrong direction.

Comment: Oh, I missed that dupes are still visible., sorry thanks

Comment: Someone who speaks Python want to confirm that it is reasonable to merge answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616415/size-of-pickled-numpy-arrays) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113549/sys-getsizeof-vaue-of-numpy-ndarray-seems-too-small) into [this master question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047388/sys-getsizeoflist-returns-less-than-the-sum-of-its-elements)?

Comment: @CodyGray They're all essentially on the same subject.  Although, I don't have the same point of view as CAFEBABE.  [The original answer from 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047523/106769) says what the other two answers say more concisely.  But I suppose understanding it depends on having some background with C/C++.

Comment: Well, I can tell you are neither a C nor C++ expert, since you referenced a mythical language, "C/C++", that does not exist, @Conspicuous. :-)

Comment: Pointer arithmetic logic for simple data types is sufficiently similar between the two that I don't really have a problem treating them as the same language for this purpose, but fair.  C is certainly the language of choice if one wishes to be exacting in small differences.